# Why $location doesn't work on mouseover using angular? It doesn't redirect me to another page

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to display a page depending on which link the cursor is over. So if the cursor is over 'Page 1' link, it will display page1.html. But when I hover, nothing happens. It goes to that page only if I click the link. Maybe I don't inject $location properly, or I need something else to fire the event.

Here is my code:

controllers.js

```
angular.module('app', ['ngRoute'])
  .controller('mainController', function ($scope) {
      $scope.title = "Angular Hover Example";
  })

  .directive('redirectOnHover', function ($location) {
      return {
          link: function (scope, element) {
              element.bind('mouseover', function (e) {
                  var address = element.attr('href');
                  address = address.substring(1, (address.length - 1)); //address is page1

                  scope.$apply(function () {
                      $location.path('/' + address);
                })
            })
        }
    }
  })
  .config(function ($routeProvider) {
      $routeProvider
        .when('/page1', {
            templateUrl: './pages/page1.html'
        })
```

index.html

```
    <ul>
        <li><a redirect-on-hover id="button1" href="#page1">Page 1</a></li>
        <li><a redirect-on-hover id="button2" href="#page2">Page 2</a></li>
        <li><a redirect-on-hover id="button3" href="#page3">Page 3</a></li>
        <li><a redirect-on-hover id="button4" href="#page4">Page 4</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: you have `ng-view` on your page. Though your URL's should look like `#/page1`

Comment: @PankajParkar I changed it to #/page1 but it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: @PankajParkar Ok. I fixed it. I shouldn't pu substring to be up to length-1. It was my fault.